# What's the best way to create an extension for Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm currently researching what the best way to create an extension for Internet Explorer would be.  The extension would simply consist of a button in the toolbar that when clicked, opens a program and sends info from the current page to the program.

I'm seen a few tutorials for C++ and C#, however, many of these appear dated as they are written for VS 2005.  I currently have VS2008 Express Edition and VS2010 Professional.

Is there a tutorial for the 2010 version of Visual Studio I can look into?  Or is there a simpler way to create an extension for Internet Explorer rather than creating a .dll (such as creating a simple .json file like for Google Chrome)?

Comment: VS2005 isn't that old, you should be looking more at what version of .net they are for. VS2005 is for .net 2. We are now on .net 4, but in my limmited knowledge i don't think anything relivent to a simple extension should have changed. (or at least I don't think there are new technologies you should be wanting ot take advantage of.) if you want to match the tuit exactly you can set your project to be creating for .net 2.0 framework

Comment: Could you provide some measure or constraints that would help someone decided if a solution is 'the best way'?

Comment: I suppose 'the best way' in this situation would be a short development time.  If the method is simplistic, that would also be a bonus.

Comment: Well, here's what I have so far: I was able to add a button to the Internet Explorer toolbar by editing the registry.  I created a .bat file that does this for me.

However, the button does not have any real functionality.  As is, it only executes an application.  I was wondering if any one knew the best way to the whole document they are browsing to another application.  I'm currently looking at COM .DLLs or "script" (I am unsure as to which scripting language Microsoft is talking about in its tutorials, nor how it is able to access the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own question...

I started creating my toolbar in C# using Visual Studio.  My project is set up as a class library, and in the project settings, I've signed my assembly with a key (so that it will work in Internet Explorer).  I'm not exactly sure how to put this, but I'm using BHO.

In order to actually use the .dll that is built, I use the following command line that I put into a file called install.bat that is in the same directory as the .dll:

```
:: Run as admin

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /f /i "%~dp0*.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /unregister "%~dp0*.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "%~dp0*.dll"
PAUSE
```

The paths are dependent on your file system though (also, if in Win7, you need to Run as Administrator).  And viola, the toolbar appears in IE.